# Viewport on Opera Mini & WM6.1 does not match 100% of the `device-width`

Tags: android, scale, viewport, opera-mini, opera-mobile

- sample page: [256.cz/test/](http://256.cz/test/)
  with code: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"
- same CSS style for mobile view and normal view
- latest Opera Mini from Android Market (Android version 2.1) - scale is not 100% :-(
- latest Opera Mini from site Opera (Windows Mobile 6.1, Native Opera Mini, Not Java) - scale is not 100% :-(
- latest Opera Mini from site Opera (Sony Ericsson W995) - scale 100% :-)
- latest Opera Mini from site Opera (BlackBerry) - scale 100% :-)

How to achieve proper display (scale 100%) on all mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mini will set the device-width to something that makes sense, considering font size and so on. E.g. on the HTC Desire, the default zoom level is 170%, resulting in a device-width of 282px (480px/1.7). target-densitydpi=device-dpi however is only supported by Opera Mobile, not by Opera Mini.

In other words, at present, there is no way to force that 1 CSS pixel equals 1 device pixel on Opera Mini.

Comment: Ah! I guess that finally answers my [questions](https://twitter.com/hexalys/status/595399864105578496). I am not liking the fact that it reports an inaccurate screen size of the device. Is there a way to at least detect tablet vs. phone factor by any chance?