# how to set css rules with @media for different screens

Tags: html, css, mobile, opera

I have following html.

```
<div id="menu">
 <div><span class="cr">Login</span><span class="cl">Welcome</span></div>
</div>
```

and following css

```
#head{background-color:#fef}
#head div{margin:0 auto;max-width: 800px;}
@media (max-device-width: 321px){
    .cr{text-align: center;display:block;}
        /*#head div{text-align: center;margin: auto;}*/
        #head div{margin: auto;text-align: center;width: 100%;}
        .root{font-size: 100%;}
};
@media (min-device-width:321px)and(max-device-width: 801px) {
    /*.cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{text-align: center;margin: auto;}*/
        .root{font-size: 128%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
};
@media (min-device-width:801px)and(max-device-width: 1025px) {
    /*.cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{text-align: center;margin: auto;}*/
        .root{font-size: 196%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
};
@media (min-device-width: 1024px) {
    /*.cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{text-align: center;margin: auto;}*/
        .root{font-size: 256%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
};
```

I just like to have two column layout for big screen and one column layout for smaller ones, but it seems it's not working or I'm doing something wrong, the css is just for mobile devices(different css file for desktops), I test it with opera mobile emulator.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use max-width: `@media screen and (max-width:800px)`. Checkout this working example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doxaras/fjrWn/2/)

Comment: Does this hint help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271128/min-width320px-not-firing-correctly-on-opera-mini-for-android

Comment: no dude, I even tested it with google chrome mobile emulator, same result, it seems browser doesn't find the query, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Dude, I found the issue! it's very ridiculous! you may check my answer, many thanks for the JS Fiddle, helped somehow :D

Answer (score 0):

WOW! what the ... issue! it doesn't work due to `;` after `@media` closing bracket!
Just removed the `;`s and it's working like charm!
I really didn't expect that!

```
@media (max-width:800px) and (min-width:320px){
        .root{font-size: 128%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{margin:0 auto;max-width: 800px;text-align: left;}
}
@media (max-width:1280px)and (min-width:800px){
        .root{font-size: 196%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{margin:0 auto;max-width: 800px;text-align: left;}
}
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width:1280px) {
        .root{font-size: 256%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{margin:0 auto;max-width: 800px;text-align: left;}
}
@media (max-width: 3840px) and (min-width:1920px) {
        .root{font-size: 512%;}
        .cr{width: 50%;float:right;text-align:right;}
        #head div{margin:0 auto;max-width: 800px;text-align: left;}
}
```